# Join all column values into one separate column

Tags: r

**Input**
`Column1`
a;b 
c;d
e;f

**Output**
`Column1` `Column2`
a;b            a;b,c;d,e;f
c;d
e;f

I want all the values of Column1 concatenated with a delimiter into one single column in one cell in Column2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With base R, we can initialize the column with `NA`. Then, we can turn the column into one string and remove the extra spaces and commas and replace with `;`.

```
df$Column2 <- NA
df$Column2[1] <- gsub(" ", "", toString(df$Column1))
```

Or here is a `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Column2 = ifelse(row_number()==1, str_replace_all(toString(Column1), " ", ""), NA))
```

**Output**

```
  Column1     Column2
1     a;b a;b,c;d,e;f
2     c;d        <NA>
3     e;f        <NA>
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  structure(list(Column1 = c("a;b", "c;d", "e;f")),
            class = "data.frame",
            row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Comment: The option of initializing the column with NA has worked for me, though on my side I used the delimiter as `,`

Comment: @FredKwebiha Sorry, I didn't catch that. I've updated the answer so that the commas are not removed.

Comment: Just leave the  code the way it was like before. I just said my code changed to `gsub(", ", ",", toString(df$Column1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
a <- data.frame(col1 = c("a;b","c;d","e;f"),
                col2 = "") # or NA if want to initialize as NA

a[1,2] <- paste(a[,1], collapse = ",")
# col1        col2
# 1  a;b a;b,c;d,e;f
# 2  c;d            
# 3  e;f
```